IOS App's Document Folder No Longer Accessible from Files App After iOS 18 Update
After updating iOS 18, I noticed that the my app's document folder is no longer accessible from the Files app. However, the files are still visible when I check the app’s storage in the settings under "Documents." This issue does not occur on iOS 17, where the app's document folder is accessible without any problems.
I have the following configurations in the Info.plist:
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>

Has anyone else experienced this issue or found a solution? Is there a new configuration or permission required for iOS 18 to maintain file sharing functionality?
Additional details:
app is installed via iTunes in company enrolled devices

In my case, the files were downloading and showing in the Files app on a simulator (iOS 18.1), but not on my actual device. After an embarrassing amount of time trying different things, my boss suggested restarting my device, and it worked straight away. I am happy that my issue is solved, but very grumpy that it was just a case of switching it off and on again!

Besides the key LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace you already have, try adding the following key to your Info.plist:
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<true/>


I have just tried this and it is still not working for me. It must be a permission thing though; will keep digging...

after 18.1 update my issue resolved automatically

@RaGibNoor nice, thank you for the update
